# htaccess url as parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi all and thanks in advance, I'm trying to add a url as a parameter but I can not.
My rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^info/([a-zA-Z0-9|]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ info.php?user=$1&text=$2&url=$3
```

In the browser:
`http://localhost/example/info/peter/hi guy/http://www.example.com`

Return array `$_GET` php

```
[user] => peter
[text] => hi guy / http:
[url] => www.example.com
```

What would be correct:

```
[user] => peter
[text] => hi guy
[url] => http://www.example.com
```

I hope your help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^info/([a-zA-Z0-9|]+)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ info.php?user=$1&text=$2&url=$3 [B,QSA]
```

`[^/]` means "any character that's not a slash". Naturally this means that "text" cannot contain any slashes, but your URL will be matched correctly.

Also note the `[B]` which is one of many options you can add to a rewrite rule. `[B]` means that any `&`s and some other characters will be escaped. So if the URL that you're as a parameter has a query string, it can be read out in `$_GET['url']` where its parameters would otherwise be interepreted as part of the new query string.

Comment: Hi good morning, everything worked properly until I got to a URL 
http://www.example.com?foo=34 type or http://www.example.com/index.php? 
user = 4 & w = This-cat 

That should change in the htaccess to support all types of URLs. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's called greedy matching .. the "dot-asterisk" matches as much as it can & then backtracks. Instead use [^/] which will match up to the next slash.

Comment: For more information about greedy matching, see [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost/example/info/peter/hi/guy/http://www.example.com` is not a valid URL for what you're trying to do. The URL part should be urlencoded.  See [this explanation](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm), for example.

The correct URL would be:

```
http://localhost/example/info/peter/hi/guy/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com
```

Nothwithstanding this point, the error with your regex is greedy matching as described in another answer.  However if you encoded the URL correctly, that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Seb, see my answer. As long as you manage to match the sub-URL correctly and add the `[B]` flag, it should work just fine without encoding the URL when generating the link.

Comment: @nitro2k01, yes, but the example the OP gives is an invalid URL and I thought that was worth pointing out.

Comment: Not really... The only invalid thing about it has nothing to do with the sub-URL; it is the space, which should be encoded to %20. Even if SA's parser doesn't like URLs with unencoded spaces, browsers encode spaces automatically in href attributes etc. Not a problem. On the other hand, there's nothing invalid about passing colons and slashes in a URL, even if / and %2F are interpreted differently by the server. Then there's the user friendliness aspect... You might want to allow the user easily smack his/her own URL parameter at the end of the URL, without having to escape the characters.

Answer (score -1):

Not my area of expertise, but why not use a $_SERVER request for the url?

It may work, may not, and that way if the domain ever changes then there is no need to update anything.

Hope this helps.