# How to set .htaccess to use prettylinks and pass URL through as parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

My question is very similar to this one, but for some reason the .htaccess solution there doesn't work for me:
[htaccess url as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513604/htaccess-url-as-parameter)

I want to pass a non-encoded URL through as a URL variable to a PHP script.  It works if I do:

http://mydomain.com/url.php?url=http://google.com

But not if I try to use prettylinks with the help of .htaccess, example:

http://mydomain.com/url/http://google.com

My .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ url.php?url=$1 [B,QSA]
```

I'm using $_GET['url'] to capture the variable in PHP and echo it.  It's SUPER close, as you can see from the page output. The problem seems to be that the 2nd slash in the URL doesn't make it through:

```
Input URL = http:/google.com
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I *sorta* fixed it by writing this PHP:

```
// Input vars
$url = $_GET['url'];

// Reformat URL because htaccess fvcks it up
if (substr($url,0,6) == "http:/" && substr($url,6,1) != "/")
$url = str_replace("http:/","http://",$url);
```

But not I notice that if I add any variables to the URL variable itself, they get passed through in separate indices in the $_GET array:

```
http://mydomain.com/url/http://google.com/?a=123
```

Results in:

```
$_GET = Array ( [url] => http:/google.com/ [a] => 123 )
```

And

```
http://mydomain.com/url?url=http://google.com/?a=123
```

Results in:

```
$_GET = Array ( [url] => http://google.com/?a=123 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `http:` prefix and `:` in GETs and generally in URLs. That is what causes the error. The server stop reading `$_GET['url']` there because it detects another http request. Just don't use `http:` or any other things that has `:` in it (just like `file:`).

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I need it to be able to work like this :)  And I've seen it work this this on other sites so I know there MUST be a way.

Comment: @Kane Yes... With .htaccess and PHP you can't do that. Just delete the http: part and add it later. With normal GETs the server knows what he is expecting: a string! With Rewrite Rules you just can't! Period. If you want to listen to me, good. Otherwise just don't ask questions you don't want answers to.

Comment: Ok, can you explain why the correct answer was accepted here then?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513604/htaccess-url-as-parameter

Comment: @Kane, That's the last time I'll tell you, then do what you like. It's highly discourage (and when I mean HIGHLY I seriously mean it) to use anything that has `:` in URLs. Both rewrited or not. It's possible but you should NOT do it. Just pass `google.com` as parameter and in your PHP script do: `$_GET['url'] = 'http:'. $_GET['url'];`. Now `$_GET['url']` is "http:google.com". Magic!

Comment: Dude, not sure why you're getting so upset. The reason I want it to work this way is for USEABILITY so that ANYONE visiting the site can simply PASTE their URL into the address bar and it will load the share buttons at the top with their site in an iframe. Most people will get confused by having to remove the http:// from the beginning. Get it now? So if it is indeed possible, PLEASE tell me the SOLUTION rather than being so condescending.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to htmlspecialchars() your URL you are passing.