# getting date from url and return json

Tags: node.js, centos

Using the simple example

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var output = {message: "Hello World!"};
  var body = JSON.stringify(output);

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  });
  res.end(body);
});
```

I can return json object. How Can I return some parameters from request like this

```
url: http://localhost:8080/get/jhon
output: {"message": "Hello jhon"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a checker for the `request.url`

basically, using your own code as an example:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var output = {message: "Hello World!"};
  var body = JSON.stringify(output);
  res.writeHead(200, {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"      
  });
  //.split creates an array with strings from the given url
  //req.url -> gives everything that's right after the http://localhost:8080/ portion
  var requested = req.url.split("/");
  output.message = "Hello " + requested[2]; // 0 is empty, 1 is "get"
  res.end(output);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: found the better way require('url').parse(req.url)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the .htaccess file to parse the URL as parameters.  See this question for an example: [htaccess url as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513604/htaccess-url-as-parameter)