# Allow urls as get parameters through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a specific htaccess rule I need to write to allow a url as a GET parameter. For example: http://example.com/test/?url=http://localhost&foo=bar or http://example.com/test/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&foo=bar

Answer (score 0):

To use URL parameter in _GET string, you need to encode it first. In PHP, for example, it is done by

```
urlencode
```

function.

So your link
http://example.com/test/?url=http://localhost&foo=bar
is invalid and it should be encoded as your second sample.

If everything's okay with this, you can use URLS as GET parameters all you want. Just don't forget that you should use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
```

Not the RewriteRule.

Here's a great sample:

http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/

Answer (score -1):

Look at this post, it might help:
[htaccess url as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513604/htaccess-url-as-parameter)

Maybe try to look at least at the 10 first Google results when you have a problem. ;)