# PHP redirect to a link in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

For my affiliate links I want them to be redirect through an intermediate page (calling it routers) to measure certain datas and efficiency.

Assuming I have my affiliate link as `www.affiliate.in?id=sdff&para=dshjgsf&aaffid=JAHAJEE` 
and an intermediate page `www.mysite.com/redirect.php?someid=1&otherid=2&url=THE_URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO`

My problem is that affiliate links have `?` and `&` and so when I use my affiliate link in this router URL, I am unable to get complete `$_GET[url]` ! Any help on how to do it with these additional parameters intact ?

Comment: With `{QUERY_STRING}` for `htaccess`. Read document https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: `urlencode` / `rawurlencode`

Comment: @jahajee.com Show your htaccess code

Answer (score 1):

**Encode the Url**

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

pass the THE_URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO  to the function

as

```
 urlencode(THE_URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO )
```

[php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Encode your url and use it (**[urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)**)

```
<?php 
$afurl = urlencode('http://www.affiliate.in?id=sdff&para=dshjgsf&aaffid=JAHAJEE');
$url = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/redirect.php?someid=1&otherid=2&url='.$afurl;
echo $url;
?>
```

this urlencode encrypt all of your special characters.

if you want to get url using htacces use the following link. This will guide you lot.

**[htaccess url as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513604/htaccess-url-as-parameter)**

The major issue i think you get the URL in this format `[a-zA-Z0-9|]` you need to change it to `(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the values passed in the url by

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```